# Using Modern System Fonts

Tags: feature-request, design

I’m wondering if it’s a good idea/time for Stack Overflow to adopt modern system fonts of different platforms. Most platforms, mobile or desktop, have their dedicated typeface now, some even offer the mono variants of the typeface. On macOS and iOS, the San Francisco is the system font, and on Android, Roboto is the system typeface.

GitHub has already done this for more than a year, and the result is very appealing, especially on the mobile platform as the website looks more familiar to the visitor since the typography stays consistent between the UI and the website.

As stated [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/), this can be achieved by using a more general value for `font-family`:

```
/* System Fonts as used by GitHub */
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

and for the monospace, GitHub currently uses this:

```
font-family: "SFMono-Regular", Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
```

Since most of these fonts are preserving the main characteristics of their old variants, e.g., Helvetica and Arial, they have minimal impacts on the layout of a website, or an app.

Update: As @Stijn suggested, I've added two screenshots with different fonts on macOS.

**Helvetica and Menlo**

[image: Helvetica and Menlo]

---

**San Francisco and San Francisco Mono**

[image: San Francisco and San Francisco Mono]

Comment: Sounds interesting. Some comparison screenshots would be useful for gathering feedback.

Comment: Understand WHY a font exists or was developed as part of the metric other than "someone picked a default font because it is pretty/unique to our platform".  For example Century Schoolbook was developed for books to enhance reading comprehension of content.  Choice of a font to jamb more content into less space is less appealing to me frankly.

Comment: I'm lucky, the designer picked the worst possible font for Windows.  Anybody that chooses Arial has a secret agenda.  Remapping it was not hard.  Surely this is possible on macOS as well?

Comment: Why not just stick to `serif`, `sans-serif`, and `monospace` and let the browser/user decide?